# Name That... Name? 3

Tags: riddle, knowledge

An illusion of Hindu mind

A writer of a different kind

Ruins crawl of apocalyptic gore

I am seen with either 3 or 4

What is this name?

Hint 1

> The last line in the poem references the two main spellings of the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is:

> Maya

An illusion of Hindu mind

> Maya is illusion in Hindi. Also known as the Goddess of illusions by Hindus.

A writer of a different kind

> This refers to a writer, probably [Maya Angelou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_Angelou)

Ruins crawl of apocalyptic gore

> This is the Maya Civilization or the Mayans who practiced Human Sacrifice and predicted the end of the world(?) (The Apocalyptic gore)

I am seen with either 3 or 4

> Maya or May, I think, as an alternative spelling.

Answer (score -1):

I think its,

> Rabindranath Tagore

who

> was, a person of wide knowledge and a fantastic writer

working on explanation

Comment: Incorrect, but a decent thought nonetheless